java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.companyname.getinfo.MainActivity"
Я создал приложение для андроид (я новичек в андроид), по обычному оно запускается отлично, и всё работает. Я добавил возможность делиться какими то данными из других приложений, моя цель просто передать ссылку из ТикТок, в мое приложение. И так я нажимаю поделиться и мое приложение как только открылось так и закрылось сразу же. Я попробовал посмотреть через отладку дабы понять что произошло, и мне выдало исключение такое:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException
Сообщение = Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.companyname.getinfo/com.companyname.getinfo.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.companyname.getinfo.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~v-k7TjscHXTT2EhuVArJKg==/com.companyname.getinfo-PDEmmFduIcvgZzYpJCl7Zg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~v-k7TjscHXTT2EhuVArJKg==/com.companyname.getinfo-PDEmmFduIcvgZzYpJCl7Zg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~v-k7TjscHXTT2EhuVArJKg==/com.companyname.getinfo-PDEmmFduIcvgZzYpJCl7Zg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]

Уточню, по обычному приложение запускается, всё работает, когда вот так, то выдает исключение. Скорее всего проблема в AndroidManifest.xml, он ругается на путь к MainActivity, когда я задаю путь в манифесте через .MainActivity то он по идее сам должен скушать такой путь, но не знаю точно ли так, вот мой манифест:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.companyname.getinfo">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="GetInfo">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest> ```


На первый взгляд смущает отсутствие дефолтного интент-фильтра. Попробуйте его вернуть: `

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>`


Я попробовал добавить это в манифест, теперь при обычном запуске я тоже получаю исключение. Ошибка точно такая же как и в вопросе, но кроме рандомных штук по типу этого k7TjscHXTT2EhuVArJKg. Только они изменились.

Единственное решение, которое я нашел, это переход на Android Studio, и там всё нормально работает, не нужно костылить как то.
Еще и решений кучу нагуглить можно. Быстрее сделал чем на языке котором знаю.
